# rfkill does not work for all the devices listed

Tags: 11.10, rfkill

when I write rfkill list I get this

```
0: sony-wifi Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

the acer-wireless does not change no matter what I do. I checked the switch gave the rfkill unblock all it works for all the other exepct for that one.

Comment: Pop your battery and leave it out.  Act like you're starting the laptop(push the power button and hold for 30 seconds).  Reinsert the battery.  Boot.  Done.  acer-wireless has had all kinds of failure to resume from soft-block bugs(as has intel).  This solution works most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove acer-wmi, does your wireless come to life?

```
    sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
    sudo rfkill unblock all
```

If so, blacklist it:

```
    sudo su
    echo "blacklist acer-wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
    exit
```

Comment: It worked!!! Me and my friend love you so much Thanks