# wifi does not work on hp pavillion. got report from wireless info script

Tags: wireless

I have ubuntu 16.04 on an hp pavillion and the wifi does not work. not an expert but I saw [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos). It told me to use this wierd script so this is the output:

http://hastebin.com/zolequyize.vbs

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42842/discussion-on-question-by-james-tobin-wifi-does-not-work-on-hp-pavillion-got-re).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is evidently the same as with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219116/rfkill-does-not-work-for-all-the-devices-listed) question. You can test it out by doing

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

You can then make this permanent by doing

```
sudo su
echo "blacklist acer-wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```